# where should I release the camera in my android activity

Tags: android, camera, release, led, flashlight

I am making an android flashlight app. I it has two activities, a main activity and a settings activity where the camera led can be toggled on and off. It also has another class where all the camera changes are handled like opening it, releasing it, and turning the light on and off.

I kept getting errors when turning on the led based on shared preference settings because I was not opening and releasing the camera in the correct activity lifecycle stages. I fixed the issues by releasing the camera when onPause is called in either activity and turning the led on or off (based on shared preference settings) when onResume is called in either activity.

The problem I am having now is that if the led is on, it turns off briefly when switching from one activity to the other because I have to release the camera and then open again in the new activity. Can anyone help me figure out a way to eliminate this problem? Where should I open and release the camera? I have tried releasing it in on destroy but the led stays on when the app is minimized to the background, which is undesirable. Thanks for any suggestions.

In both main and settings activity I have:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() { 
        super.onResume();

        if (sp.getBoolean("LED_TOGGLE_CB", false) == true) {
            flash.turnFlashOn();
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        flash.killCamera();
    }
```

In the Flash class I have:

```
void getCamera() {
    if(camera == null) {
        try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();

        } catch(RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

void turnFlashOn() {
    getCamera();

    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    camera.setParameters(params);
    camera.startPreview();
    isFlashOn = true;
}

public void killCamera() {
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should share relevant code to help us.

Comment: @user3143158 Why kill and not release??

Comment: I have solved this issue by using fragments so that there is only one activity. Thanks